# Rigid Body Problem - Objects not interacting with curves correctly

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to make my own Jenga tower with blocks sliding out to practice rigid body simulations. When my blocks fall, they are interacting with the bottom of the plane but slide right through the beveled mesh. The plane, as well as the blocks, are set as rigid bodies and the blocks are active while the plane is passive. Here is the blend file if anyone wants to take a closer look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwyg5bh0otwjx9l/JengaBlockCopy.blend?dl=0 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you did the simulation when that plane was flat, then you baked the simulation and then edited the plane to have a bevelled wall. To fix this, go to the Rigid Body cache, delete the bake, and re-bake. Make sure the plane Shape option is set to Mesh and not Convex Hull.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I did exactly what you said and the blocks still slid right through the curved edge.

Comment: Nevermind! I had to add a solidify modifier to the plane! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change to shape "mesh" and "deform"

[image]

result:

[image]